# Implementing combineReducers using ```for...in```?

Tags: javascript, redux

In lesson 16 of the [egghead.io series on Redux](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-implementing-combinereducers-from-scratch), I tried to implement my own combineReducers function before looking at how Dan did it. I got as far as the following. I tried  to use `for ... in` on the sub-reducers (`todos`, `visibilityFilter`) passed in like so

```
const combineReducers  = (reducers) => {
   return (state,action) => {
    let temp = {};
    for (let i in reducers) {
      temp[i] =  reducers[i](state,action)
    }
    return temp;

  }
}
```

This does not work. When I test it with the expect library, I receive the following error in the console. Strangely, if I'm not mistaken, it looks like the state from the call to the `todos` reducer has been nested in to the call of the `visibilityFilter` reducer. This is very odd as my code shows them being distinctly separate fields in the object returned.

> Uncaught Error: Expected { todos: [ { completed: false, id: 1, text:
>   'Go shopping' } ], visibilityFilter: { todos: [ { completed: false,
>   id: 0, text: 'Learn Redux' } ], visibilityFilter: 'SHOW_ALL' } } to
>   equal { todos: [ { completed: false, id: 0, text: 'Learn Redux' }, {
>   completed: false, id: 1, text: 'Go shopping' } ], visibilityFilter:
>   'SHOW_ALL' }

My test code is

```
const testTodoApp = () => {
  const stateBefore = {
    todos: [{id: 0, text:'Learn Redux', completed: false}],
    visibilityFilter: 'SHOW_ALL',
  };

  // action is an object. with a defined type property.
  const action = {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    id: 1,
    text: 'Go shopping',
  };

  const stateAfter = {
    todos: [{id: 0, text:'Learn Redux', completed: false},
            {id: 1, text:'Go shopping', completed: false},
            ],
    visibilityFilter: 'SHOW_ALL',
  };

  deepFreeze(stateBefore);
  deepFreeze(action);

  expect(
    todoApp(stateBefore, action)
  ).toEqual(stateAfter);
  console.log("Test passed: todoApp")

}

testTodoApp();
```

This test will pass if I use the built-in combineReducers.
The sub-reducers and call to `combineReducers` are as follows:

```
const todo = (state = {} ,action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case 'ADD_TODO':
    return {
      id: action.id, text: action.text, completed: false,
    };

    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
    if (state.id !== action.id) {
      return state;
    }
    return {
      ...state, completed: !state.completed,
    };

    default:
    return state;

  }

}
const todos = (state=[], action) =>{

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
    console.log('ADD_TODO switch selected')
    return [
      ...state,
      todo(undefined,action),
    ];

    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
    console.log('TOGGLE_TODO switch selected')

    return state.map( t => todo(t, action))

    default:
    console.log('default switch selected')
    return state;
  }
}

const visibilityFilter = (
  state = 'SHOW_ALL',
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER':
      return action.filter;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}


const todoApp = combineReducers({
  todos,
  visibilityFilter,
})
```

My questions are:

1. What was it in my code that caused this nesting of one reducer within the other?
2. I realize Dan used `reduce` instead, but for pedagogical reasons, how can I go about using the `for ... in` pattern to implement combineReducers?
3. After that, can you please comment on the appropriateness of using `for ... in` for such applications, and if it is a bad pattern, what is it that makes it so?

Answer (score 3):

I just realized that the `todos` reducer and `visibilityFilter` reducers have to be passed the part of the combined state that corresponds to *their* key, not the entire combined state. So the working code should look like this, where I have added an object accessor to the corresponding part of the state in the 5th line.

```
const combineReducers  = (reducers) => {
   return (state,action) => {
    let temp = {};
    for (let i in reducers) {
      temp[i] =  reducers[i](state[i],action)
    }
    return temp;

  }
}
```